# C# Find a specific object by searching one of its variable

Tags: c#, class, object

So I'm trying to do something similar to how you do it in JavaScript by `getElementById`.

I want to do something like this:

```
class Animal 
{  
   string id; 
}

public Animal Zebra = new Animal();
Zebra.id = "abc";

//and then get it like this
var foo = getAnimalId("abc");
```

And it returns Zebra. Any way to do this? Thanks

Comment: Get it from where? is this in a list of animals? an element on an asp page?

Comment: Use a `Dictionary<string, Animal>` where the key is the ID. Then you can get it with: `Animal a; dict.TryGetValue("abc", out a);`

Answer (score 2):

Use a `Dictionary<string, Animal>` where the key is the ID. Then you can get it with [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.TryGetValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var animalIDs = new Dictionary<string, Animal>();
animalIDs.Add(Zebra.id, Zebra);
```

// ....

```
Animal animal; 
bool containsAnimalID = animalIDs.TryGetValue("abc", out animal);
if(containsAnimalID)
{
    // do something with the zebra ...
}
```

Comment: Depending on the objects, it might be better to just use `object`, or maybe even `Control` instead of specifically `Animal`. If they are wanting something similar to getElementById to get a reference to a control on the form, it would probably be better to use something a bit less specific of a type. But that is just a guess/assumption on my part.

Comment: @gmiley: it was just an example, instead of `Animal`(which already seems to be a base class) he could also use `Control` or whatever. The idea should be clear, the key is the ID and the value the object. Allowing `Object` as value seems to be too generous.

Answer (score 0):

The question is quite vague, so it's hard to understand what kind of help you need. But i'll try to give you an answer.

First you have to store the animals in something like a list.

```
public List<Animal> _animals = new List<Animal>();
```

And when you're creating the animals, you'll have to add them to the list.

```
Animal zebra = new Animal();
zebra.id = "abc";

_animals.Add(zebra);
```

You can then check if an animal with id `abc` exists like this:

```
if(_animals.Any(a => a.id == "abc"))
```

and get the animal like this:

```
Animal animal = _animals.FirstOrDefault(a => a.id == "abc");
```

`List.FirstOrDefault()` allows you to get the first animal matching the id, and if none exists, you get `null` returned.